# What do these Square Brackets C# syntax mean infront of Function Parameters? It looks like attributes

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I'm trying to work out what this code does. It's part of the .NET framework and MS Azure; I have a C++ background, but (obviously) C# is a different animal.

Having spent much time googling "square bracket use in c#" I believe that the first use of the square brackets is for an attribute.
But I've found nothing that says there can be attributes as part of a parameter within a function call, and can find no information on the subject..

I'm pretty sure they're not indexers, what does the syntax in the first set of square brackets represent? (Shown below:)

```cs
[FunctionName("orderProcessor")]
```

```cs
[FunctionName("orderProcessor")]
public static void Run(
   [ServiceBusTrigger("ordersTopic)] string myQueueItem,
   [Blob("orders/{id}",FileAccess.Write] Stream order,
   ILogger log )
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, attributes can apply to a method or to the arguments of a method.

Comment: Yes, they're [attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes). Here's the list of [things an attribute can target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attributetargets?view=net-6.0#fields).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/). There is an entire article about them in C#

Aside from many "built-in" (based on nuget packages), you can also freely define your own [custom attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/creating-custom-attributes).